# How to call ** var in C/C++ 10.5 chapter numerical recipes

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I have a problem with calling this function:

```c
void powell(float p[], float **xi, int n, 
            float ftol, int *iter, float *fret, 
            float (*func)(float []))
```

I don't know which argument must be under **xi to run my code.

Whole function below:

```
void powell(float p[], float** xi, int n, float ftol, int* iter, float* fret, float (*func)(float[]))
{
    void linmin(float p[], float xi[], int n, float* fret, float (*func)(float[]));
    int i, ibig, j;
    float del, fp, fptt, t, *pt, *ptt, *xit;
    pt = vector(1, n);
    ptt = vector(1, n);
    xit = vector(1, n);
    *fret = (*func)(p);
    for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        pt[j] = p[j];
    for (*iter = 1;; ++(*iter)) {
        fp = (*fret);
        ibig = 0;
        del = 0.0;
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)
                xit[j] = xi[j][i];
            fptt = (*fret);
            linmin(p, xit, n, fret, func);
            if (fptt - (*fret) > del) {
                del = fptt - (*fret);
                ibig = i;
            }
        }
        if (2.0 * (fp - (*fret)) <= ftol * (fabs(fp) + fabs(*fret)) + TINY) {
            free_vector(xit, 1, n);
            free_vector(ptt, 1, n);
            free_vector(pt, 1, n);
            return;
        }
        if (*iter == ITMAX)
            nrerror("powell exceeding maximum iterations.");
        for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
            ptt[j] = 2.0 * p[j] - pt[j];
            xit[j] = p[j] - pt[j];
            pt[j] = p[j];
        }
        fptt = (*func)(ptt);
        if (fptt < fp) {
            t = 2.0 * (fp - 2.0 * (*fret) + fptt) * SQR(fp - (*fret) - del) - del * SQR(fp - fptt);
            if (t < 0.0) {
                linmin(p, xit, n, fret, func);
                for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
                    xi[j][ibig] = xi[j][n];
                    xi[j][n] = xit[j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your code and fix the indention. The code is not readable.

Comment: What makes you think readers will know either? Where did this code come from? Is it part of a library? Is there any documentation? What are you hoping to use the code to achieve? etc.

Comment: This code comes from Numerical Recipes. It's chapter 10.5

Comment: `xi` is a "simulated" or "ragged" 2D array, a pointer to some pointers to `float`.  See [question 6.16](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/dynmuldimary.html) in the old [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/l).

Comment: Note: a "`*variable`" means the function wants a pointer.  A "`**float`" means that the function wants the address of a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

A *double* pointer means that the function wants the address of a pointer.

```
void my_function(int **p_pointer)
{
  *p_pointer = new int[42];
}

int main(void)
{
   int * pointer = nullptr;
   my_function(&pointer);
   return 0;
}
```

In C++, the *double* pointer can be avoided by using reference:

```
void another_function(int *& pointer)
{
  pointer = new int [256];
}

int main(void)
{
  int p = nullptr;
  another_function(p);
  return 0;
}
```

One of the primary concerns with pointers is that they can point to *anywhere*, a defined location or not.  Testing a pointer for validity is complex because it depends on the range (or ranges) that are valid *for the current platform*.  With references, the reference is valid, by definition, so no validity checks need to be performed.